# Comparing two jumbled / unaligned text files

Tags: text, compare

I have two text files containing IL code for example, both text files include 100% the same code:

http://pastebin.com/iDvbu1tD

http://pastebin.com/u5fi9NMh

They are however unaligned / Jumbled so its not possible for me to find any differences, i am looking for a way to be able to take such files and filter out the code that is the same and only show blocks that are different.

Is there a way to do such a task ?

Answer (score 0):

First the "TL;DR": the two pastes are in fact identical, as you say, except for a simple difference in the order of the methods, and a very minor formatting problem. Namely, the `.method` line of the  middle method in each disassembly listing isn't indented by two spaces like the other two `.method` lines in the same file.

I copied the files to a Ubuntu Linux system, and took the liberty of fixing the minor `.method` formatting problem by hand in both of them.

Then I wrote some extraction code using the [TXR](http://nongnu.org/txr) language whose purpose it is to normalize the file: it extract the methods, identifying the name of each one and then prints a reformatted version of the disassembly. These reformatted versions can then be compared.

In the reformatting, the methods are sorted by name. Also, the IL_XXXX offsets on the instructions are deleted, so that minor differences, like the insertion of an instruction sequence, will not result in huge differences due to the subsequent offsets changing. However, this is not demonstrated with the given data, since the code is in fact identical.

Here is what the reformatting of one of the inputs looks like, abbreviated manually:

```
$ txr norm.txr disasm-a
  .method public hidebysig newslot virtual final instance bool IsRoomConnected() cil managed
  {
    // Code size       21 (0x15)
    .maxstack  8
    ldarg.0
    ldfld      class [UnityEngine]UnityEngine.AndroidJavaObject GooglePlayGames.Android.AndroidRtmpClient::mRoom
    brfalse    IL_0013
    ldarg.0
[ ... snip ... ]
    ldc.i4.0
    ret
  } // end of method AndroidRtmpClient::IsRoomConnected

[ ... other methods ... ]
```

The `.method` material is folded into one line, `IsRoomConnected` is first because the other two functions start with `P` and `O`, respectively, and the offsets are gone from the instructions.

Comparing the reformatted versions can be done in the Linux environment in one step without temporary files thanks to Bash "process substitution" `<(command ...)` syntax.  This syntax lets us use, in the place of a file name argument, a program which produces output.  The program which is invoked thinks it is a file:

```
$ diff -u <(txr norm.txr disasm-a) <(txr norm.txr disasm-b)
# no output!
```

That is to say, when we diff the normalized versions of the two disassembly listings, there is no output: they are character-for-character identical!

A code listing of `norm.txr` follows:

```
(collect)
@  (freeform)
  .method @decl  {
@  (bind pieces @(tok-str decl #/\S+/))
@  (bind name @(find-if (op search-str @1 "(") pieces))
@  (collect)
@    (cases)
    IL_@offset:  @line
@    (or)
    @line
@    (end)
@  (last)
  } // @eom
@  (end)
@(end)
@(set (name decl line eom) @(multi-sort (list name decl line eom)
                                        [list less]))
@(output)
@  (repeat)
  .method @decl
  {
@   (repeat)
    @line
@   (end)
  } // @eom
@  (end)
@(end)
```